# Does glPixelStore affect glCopyTexSubImage2D?

Tags: opengl

I'd like to know what, if any, `glPixelStorei` calls I need to make before `glCopyTexSubImage2D` in OpenGL 2.

I'm trying to read the docs, but I seem to be getting mixed messages.  The [man page on `glCopyTexSubImage2D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glCopyTexSubImage2D.xml) says

> The pixels in the rectangle are processed exactly as if
>       glCopyPixels had been called, but the process stops just before
>       final conversion.

That could be clearer, but makes some sense, since `glCopyTexSubImage2D` and `glCopyPixels` are both copying pixels from one place on the GPU to another.  However, the same man page also says

> glPixelStore and glPixelTransfer modes affect texture images
>       in exactly the way they affect glDrawPixels.

OK, so I'm supposed to look at `glDrawPixels` instead?

Now, in the OpenGL 2.1 specification, the table of PACK constants is labelled

> PixelStore parameters pertaining to ReadPixels, GetColorTable, GetConvolutionFilter, GetSeparableFilter, GetHistogram, GetMinmax, GetPolygonStipple, and GetTexImage

and the table of UNPACK parameters is labelled

> PixelStore parameters pertaining to one or more of DrawPixels, ColorTable, ColorSubTable, ConvolutionFilter1D, ConvolutionFilter2D, SeparableFilter2D, PolygonStipple, TexImage1D, TexImage2D, TexImage3D, TexSubImage1D, TexSubImage2D, and TexSubImage3D

but neither of those lists includes CopyTexSubImage2D, suggesting that I don't need to call `glPixelStorei`.

Comment: "Six of the twelve storage parameters affect how pixel data is returned to client memory"... "The other six of the twelve storage parameters affect how pixel data is read from client memory."   Copies within the GPU don't involve client memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glPixelStore` affects how OpenGL deals with pixels being stored in user-provided memory. `glCopyTexSubImage` does not affect user-provided memory, so it has no need to use those parameters.

Comment: Doesn't explain why `glPixelStore` is even mentioned on the man page for `glCopyTexSubImage`, but OK.